# Why is this RewriteRule not working? (xampp)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, xampp

I have set up this very simple .htaccess-file in my projects root folder `c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\`

```
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ test.php?stuff=$1 [QSA,L]
```

as well as a `test.php` (there is no index.php)

```
<?php
if (isset($GET_['stuff'])) {
    echo $GET_['stuff'];
} else {
    echo "not set";
}
```

When I visit `localhost/myproject` instead of redirecting me to `test.php` it just lists the directory structure of my project.

When I change the htaccess to something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.google.de [L]
```

everything works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why you get directory listing because your URL `localhost/myproject` actually sends an empty per-dir URI when `.htaccess` is placed inside `/myproject/`.

You URI pattern is `(.+)` that obviously won't match an empty string hence rules doesn't fire and since you don't have `index.php` or `index.html`, you get directory list.

Correct rule should be:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?stuff=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**PS:** Note that removing `RewriteCond` will invoke `test.php` for `localhost/myproject` but it will be internally invoked as `test.php?stuff=test.php&stuff=`